# Eclipse and maven project - lifecycle configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, project, squash

I have a problem when I want to import open source project Squash Test Management into eclipse as project. When I imported all projects which are found in download package, as existing maven projects, I got many projects in eclipse but in every each I have an error in pom.xml file:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
```

I suppose that something is wrong in my maven plugin in eclipse. I searching for answers but without success. Any ideas? If I did't specified enough informations let me now.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's just maven telling you that the eclipse/maven collaboration doesn't know exactly what to do with the plugin.

Go to the XML Source tab in the pom file editor and use the suggested Quick Fix for the error.  The quick fix should insert a stanza of XML that tells M2E/Eclipse how to handle the plugin.  This stanza is otherwise ignored by maven.

Once the stanza is added, look for:

```
<action>
    </ignore>
</action>
```

and replace it with

```
<action>
    <execute >
        <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
    </execute >
</action>
```